# Algebraic solution to the Broken Weight Problem

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, puzzle

Here is a problem I was sent, which it turns out was first posed by [Claude Gaspard Bachet de Méziriac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Gaspard_Bachet_de_M%C3%A9ziriac) in a book of arithmetic problems. The problem is as follows:

> A few years ago, a King's mathematics professor purchased a small farm, a place where he could unwind on the weekends and grow some fruit and vegetables. The farm came with all kinds of tools and various implements, including a large balance scale. Next to the scale was an old (pre-metric) 40 lbs stone with some initials carved into it: apparently, a previous owner had used it to weight 40 lbs of feed.
>
> One morning, while cleaning out his barn, the professor dropped the stone and it broke into four pieces.
>
> The professor was a bit sad about his carelessness, as he had liked that curious old stone. But he soon discovered something interesting: He could use the four pieces of the broken stone to weigh items on the balance scale - as long as these items were in one pound increments, between 1 and 40 pounds.
>
> How much did each of the four pieces weigh?

Note that since this was a 17th-century merchant, he of course used the balance scale to weigh things. So, for example, he could use a 1 lb weight and a 4 lb weight to weigh a 3 lb object, by placing the 3 lb object and 1 lb weight on one side of the scale, and the 4 lb weight on the other side.

I won't post the solution as maybe some of you would like to give this a go. For anyone reading this and wanting to try it themselves, DON'T SCROLL DOWN! People will be posting their solutions there.

I did this using an intuitive method but my question I am asking is in two parts:

1) Is there an algebraic solution to this without first solving it intuitively and then finding the logic

2) Is there therefore a general form you can take to solve any problem of this type?

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you can weigh $1,2,3,\ldots,40$, you can also automatically weigh $-1,-2,-3,\ldots,-40$ and trivially $0$. That is, you can determine $81=3^4$ different weights by putting each of the four weights into either of the pans or not use it. This means that the condition is "sharp" - any distinct distribution of pieces results in a distinct (integer) weight as difference between the two pans. If the pieces are $a\le b\le c\le d$, then the largest possible weights are $a+b+c+d=40$ (of course) and then $b+c+d$, which must be $39$, hence $a=1$. The next smallest weight is $b+c+d-a=38$, followed by $a+c+d$, which must be $37$, hence $b=3$. Then we already know that the sequence continues with $c+d=36$, $c+d-a=35$, $c+d-b+a=34$, $c+d-b=33$, $c+d-b-a=32$. Then the next smallest (i.e., the largest not having $+c$ and $+d$) is $a+b+d$ and must equal $31$, so that $c=9$ and finally $d=27$ (as we might have guessed meanwhile).

Comment: I don't understand how $b + c + d = 39$?

Comment: Actually, I do understand. I didn't read it properly. I do have another question though: What was the reason behind stating there is $81$ different weights?

Comment: @Kaish With four weights, we can distinguish *at most* 81 weights (including negatives) because there are 81 ways to place the weights. If there were less than $40+1+40=81$ weights that *can* be distingished, it might be the case that different combinations lead to the same weight, for example it might be the case that $b+c+d-a = a+c+d$ (i.e., $b=2a=2$); or it might even be the case that the largest weight (in continuous sequence) is less than $a+b+c+d$. By counting the $81$ weights, I know that all $\epsilon_aa+\epsilon_bb+\epsilon_cc+\epsilon_dd$ with $\epsilon_x\in\{-1,0,1\}$ are different.

Answer (score 0):

For a "fair" balance scale, in order to be able to weigh an object of weight 1 you need a 1 stone. Then  to weigh an object of weight 2 you need either a 2 stone or a 3 stone. The key point is that there is no weight achievable with stones of $(1,2)$ that is not achievable with $(1,3)$ (while $(1,3)$ can also weigh a 4 stone), so $(1,3)$ dominates over $(1,2)$ in the sense that it is always better.

Now to weigh a 3-stone you do need either $(1,2)$ or $(1,3)$ so any best solution must include $(1,3)$.  Now apply the same reasoning to 5 and you find that you need a 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9-stone, and that $(1,3,9)$ dominates.  It is easy to create an induction proof that to weigh all numbers up to $N$ with the minimum number of stones, a minimal solution is always 
of the form $\{3^k\} | 0 \leq k \leq \log_3 (3N/2)$; in the present case, $N=40$ so $k$ goes up to 3 so 4 stones suffice.

A related problem is that of the "unfair" scale, where it balances if the total weight on the left is exactly *twice* that on the right.

Comment: You do not need a 1 stone to weigh 1. For example $2, 3, 7$ allow you to weigh $1,2,3,4,5$.

Answer (score -1):

$1,3,9,27$ are the numbers that make up to $1-40\;lb$ because....

$$\begin{align}
1&=1\\
1-3&=2\\
3&=3\\
1+3&=4\\
1+3-9&=5\\
3-9&=6\\
9-1&=8\\
9&=9\\
1+9&=10\\
1-3=2+9&=11\\
\end{align}$$
and so one until you get to $40$ its quite simple once you get the $4$ numbers.